# Changing props history causes redirect loop React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-v4

Here is my code in my component:

```
class MyComp extends React.Component {

  componentDidMount(){
    this._isMounted = true;
    axios.get(URL).
    then(res => {
      if(this._isMounted) {
        if(res=="ok")
          this.props.history.push("en/dashboard");
        }
    })
  }

  componentWillUnmount(){
    this._isMounted = false;
  }
}
```

My index.js with routes:

```
<Switch>
  <Route exact path={`${match.url}/`} component={MyComp} />
  <Route path={`${match.url}/dashboard`} component={Dashboard} />
</Switch>
```

And component renders infinitely when I do the axios call and I do not know how to handle this, I just want a simple redirect to another route. Thank you!

Comment: You might be redirecting to the same route that renders this component, have you checked that :)

Comment: Go to your Router config file, and search for `/dashboard` route and check that you are not rednering `MyComp` component, if so, that is why you have a infinite redirection

Comment: Possible duplicate of [programmatically-navigate-using-react-router](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31079081/programmatically-navigate-using-react-router)

Comment: I checked and I do that, but I still do not know what to do next. :) I edited my question.

Comment: Add the `exact` prop to `<Route path={`${match.url}/dashboard`} component={Dashboard} />`

Comment: Still the same behaviour

Comment: `push("/dashboard");` but `<Route path={`${match.url}/dashboard`}`. Why `${match.url}/dashboard`  instead of '/dashboard'?

Comment: It was 'en/dashboard' up there, sorry

Comment: so why do you use `${match.url}` in your routes? and which router version are you using?

Comment: Because I use i18n for language, and my routes depend on what language is set, but what's the problem with that and my issue? All the other routes are working just fine

Comment: @c-chavez "react-router-dom": "4.3.1",

Comment: @Tobi there is no problem with `${match.url}` now that you explain, but of course if we don't know the context we cannot help. Version usually helps, because routing in react-router differs from 3 to 4 for example.

Comment: To explain a little what I want to achieve (it may be another approach, but I am new to React) : MyComp is a login page and if something happens when my app starts(I do a request to server just then), I want to skip the authentication page and jump right to dashboard, but I want to keep my login page for the other case.

Comment: @Tobi could you expand your idea with this statement: "if something happens when my app starts", what do you mean if something happens? Do you mean, you want to check if the user is already logged in (for example by checking the session with a server request), and if it is true then you want to redirect to the dashboard, skipping the login part? For me the only thing I don't understand is why are you using `_isMounted`...

Comment: Yes! That's what I want to do. I do not know also, I found a tutorial when I made my first axios request and that's how it was there and since then, I copy-paste it :)

Comment: @Tobi ok, could you please add the code of your `index.js` file, to see how you are using the router? and it would be helpful to see the code for `MyComp` as well. For me, it's weird that you check `_isMounted` for this task, so I want to completely understand what's going on. I've done this before, but in a different way.

Comment: My index.js is too big to post it ...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/182361/discussion-between-tobi-and-c-chavez).

Answer (score 0):

Seem `match.url` alway `en/dashboard` after redirect from MyComp.

Try changing the order of the Routes

```
<Switch>
    <Route path={`${match.url}/dashboard`} component={Dashboard} />
    <Route exact path={`${match.url}/`} component={MyComp} />
</Switch>
```

Comment: Nop, the same infinite loop between '/en' and '/en/dashboard'

Comment: are API call with each loop? can you `console.log(match.url)` in router after redirect?

Comment: My match.url is always '/en' when redirect. From what I see it tries to redirect me to dashboard, but sends me back to '/en' and so on

Answer (score 0):

You can try with this hope so this is help full u.

```
<Switch>
    <Route exact path={`/:language/dashboard`} component={Dashboard} />
    <Route exact path={`/:language`} component={MyComp} />
</Switch>

 class MyComp extends React.Component {

      componentDidMount(){
        this._isMounted = true;
        axios.get(URL).
        then(res => {
          if(this._isMounted) {
            if(res=="ok")
              this.props.history.push("/en/dashboard");
            }
        })
      }

      componentWillUnmount(){
        this._isMounted = false;
      }
    }
```

Comment: Could you explain why using a param would solve OP's problem rather than using `${match.url}`?

Comment: bcoz params may be dynamic so it's now en but it can be changed dc or etc... so